# How can I get Chrome to load only a part of a video for a HTML5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I have to play parts of videos on a page.

I'm using the `#t=00:10:00,00:10:30` in the `src` to read only 30 seconds of the video starting at 10 minutes into it (as an example, those value are calculated in the js based on the user request).

```
<video id="html5-video-player" 
    src="http://url.of.the/videos/foo.mp4#t=00:10:00,00:10:30"
    type="video/mp4" style="height: 179px; width: 351px;"></video>
```

The video loads fine and plays ok. But as soon as the clip is stopped, Chrome request the rest of the video (~3GB) which is a problem for me.

Any idea how to prevent that extra loading?

I have the problem using Apache or Node.js (meloncholy/vid-streamer) as server so I guess the server is not the problem here. 
I'm getting the 206 Partial requests and the servers are responding correctly to them.

So I can only guess that it's Chrome that asks for more video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hacky solution to the problem:

I add a event listener on the `pause` event and remove the `src` and it stops loading.

```
video.addEventListener('pause', stopLoading, false);

var pauseTime = 0;

function stopLoading() {
    pauseTime = Math.round(video.currentTime);
    video.src = '';
}
```

I keep track here of the currentTime of the video so if the user hits play again, the video starts playing from that point.

For this I just have to convert the recorded time into a HH:MM:SS format and set the src back to the video with the correct time.

Any other ideas are welcomed.